# Create a new data based on a data frame of multi-array (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

This is a data frame in pandas (data 1)

```
var1  var2
1     [a,b,c]
2     [d,e,f]
3     g
```

This is another data set in pandas' data frame (data 2)

```
var2  
a     
a     
b     
d       
g     
b
```

Based data1 and data2, how can I get this data?

```
var2  var1
a     1
a     1
b     1
d     2     
g     3
b     1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df2.merge(df1.explode('var2'), on='var2', how='left')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I got an error message "TypeError: explode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'column'" , do you know why is there an error message?

Comment: pretty sure it should be `df1.explode("var1")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Now I'm getting a new error message: "unhashable type: 'list'"...

Comment: @CharlotteDeng Sorry, explode on `var2`. See updated answer